# strcpy: array memory questions

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks

I'm trying to learn C++ using the book "*C++ for Lazy Programmers*" and it gives the function `myStrcpy` for copying two strings (page 306), which I used in this little example:

```
#include <iostream>

void myStrcpy(char* destination, const char* source);

int main()
{
    char ca1[] = "this";
    char ca2[] = " is a test of this.";

    myStrcpy(ca1, ca2);
    std::cout << ca1 << " \t " << ca2 << '\n';
}

void myStrcpy(char* destination, const char* source)
{
    while (*source)
        *destination++ = *source++;
    *destination = '\0'; //put null character at the end
}
```

When I try to run the program, I get the following error:
*Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'ca1' was corrupted. The error does not appear when I switch the variables, so `myStrcpy(ca2, ca1)`.

With my little knowledge of C++ and Google, I assume it is because `myStrcpy` writes into areas where it has no business writing to (since the array that is being copied to is shorter than the other one), is that right?

And if that is the case, what would be the proper procedure to implement this be? Create a new character array and then overwrite the pointer to the old one? I assume one would still have to properly free up the memory from the old one then, is that correct or does C++ handle that automatically?

Thank you in advance for your time, it's really appreciated!

Comment: If this C++ book is teaching C strings I'm already highly skeptical about its value as a tool for teaching C++. Update: I've looked at previews of the book and it looks like hot garbage, like someone just slammed this out over a weekend. I hope you can find a better resource to learn C++.

Comment: @tadman definitely! C++ books should never teach you about how things actually work, they should only teach you the abstractions that are there to make your life easier. (sarcasm)

Comment: I recommend skipping the chapter on character arrays and C-Strings and proceed directly on the chapter about `std::string`.

Comment: @user253751 Going through these exercises is fine for a *C book*, and I'd recommend understanding it if that was your goal. Bjarne's C++ book doesn't touch on this for good reason, it's C domain, not C++, and instead it explains the *Standard Library* from first principles.

Comment: @tadman Ah so everyone who learns C++ should also learn C separately in order to understand how everything works?

Comment: @user253751 Yes, as it's a different language with different objectives and strengths. This also holds true for Objective-C and any other *superset of C* type language. If you want to know how to use C++ effectively you'll *also* have to know C very well.

Comment: @tadman It's not a different language. C++ allows direct string manipulation, and in fact, one of its purported strengths is the ability to bypass all the abstraction if you have to.

Comment: @user253751 This book, which is where the question springs from, doesn't actually teach C++, it teaches fancy C using a sprinkling of C++isms here and there. It's not an effective tool for teaching C++ and doesn't, as you might insist, teach any "fundamentals". It's just a slapdash mess of junk masquerading as a book. C is a separate language. It even has its own compiler! People even write operating systems in it!

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for the back and forth! I deduce that my question was not entirely stupid then (though I wonder why it got downvoted) and my doubts about the book seem to be not entirely baseless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're copying from `ca2` - where the text `" is a test of this."` is - into `ca1` - which currently stores `"this"` and therefore has been sized for four characters plus a NUL terminator.  There's not enough room to copy into.  You should make `ca` bigger than whatever you want to copy into it, e.g.

```
char ca1[128] = "this";
```

More generally, in C++ it's best to use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to manage memory for strings - it avoids a lot of error prone buffer allocation/size/deallocation logic.  Using character arrays is a useful exercise to understand memory operations, but not good practice for general text handling.  If you want to continue with character arrays as an exercise, the next steps are learning to dynamically allocate character arrays (`new char[n]`), deallocate them (`delete[] char_array`), and use `strlen(const char*)` to find out the number of text characters (excluding the NUL terminator) in an existing buffer).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So am I right to assume that it is nearly impossible to implement such a character array safely? Because even with creating a new array, thanks to pointers it would be impossible to keep track of all the references to the original array that store that address. Is that correct?

Comment: @Markstar it's possible to do it safely - all C programs (including things like the Linux kernel) handle these kind of issues routinely (and carefully).  Usually, as much as possible, -you want one pointer variable to the character array to be stored for as long as the text is needed - that pointer variable is the "owner" of the text.  Other functions may temporarily have pointers they use to search for things in the text, or change bits - like your `myStrcpy()` function - but they don't affect the ownership of the buffers they affect.  C++ also has `std::unique_ptr<>` to manage ownership.